# Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'step()' that is not exposed to Objective-C with Timer

Tags: swift

What can cause a function that has `@objc` (and no errors related to that) to warn:

> *Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'step()' that is not exposed to Objective-C* in selector

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self,
    selector: #selector(model.step), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

with specifically:

```
// step is used to process a step in the game of life
@objc func step () {
```

and the protocol for that class:

```
// This specifies how the model must appear to the view controller
protocol GameOfLifeProtocol:class {
    var generation: Int { get }
    var complete: Bool { get set }

    func step()
```

and the instantiation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()
    var model:GameOfLifeProtocol = GameOfLife()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong selector and the wrong target for your timer.

The `step` method is in the `GameOfLifeProtocol` and you want the timer to call that `step` method on your `model` instance.

Change your timer to:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: model,
    selector: #selector(step), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Whenever you use a target/selector, the `target` is the object you want the `selector` to be called on. In this case, `self` is your `ViewController`. `ViewController` doesn't have the `step` method.

You also need to update your protocol to mark `step` with `@objc`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@objc func step() {` is not in a *place* where Objective-C can see it. It needs to be at the top level of your ViewController class. You are rightly saying that the target is `self`, the ViewController; that is where `step()` needs to be defined.

Your idea that you are going to somehow magically inject this method into ViewController by dependency injection is not going to work through a protocol extension. Objective-C can't see into the protocol extension.